# Как загрузить xls на opencart

Tags: opencart

Есть магазин на opencart Version 2.3.0.2 (trs-2.3.0.0)/ все работает заказчик прислал прайс на 2.5к товаров. Загрузку делаю через плагин Export/Import Tool (V3.9) for Ocstore 2.x. Импорт проходит успешно, только ничего не отображается нигде, подскажите как нужно правильно производить импорт товаров?

Comment: vqMod ставили? Ибо нужен.

Comment: прикрепите часть файла, который вы импортируете, возможно неправильно создан файл

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите что пишет в файле логов
Система - Обслуживание - Журнал ошибок

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/745032)